Opening scene where a man on horse rides up to a female police officer or security guard holding a bouquet
I am trying to figure out the title of a movie based on my husband's description of the opening scene.
As a child, my husband went to a movie theatre to see The Sandlot (1993), but the theatre began showing the wrong movie. In the opening scene, a man is riding a horse carrying a bouquet of roses. He rides up to a female police officer or security guard outside a building (maybe a bank or something) and holds the bouquet as if to give it to her. However, there is a gun in the flowers and he shoots her.
It's driven him crazy trying to figure out what this film is. After that scene, the movie was either turned off or his parents escorted him from the theatre since it obviously wasn't a kid-friendly film. So that's all I have to go on. Any idea what it is? Would've been in the theatre at the same time as "The Sandlot".

Hear No Evil from 1993 with Marlee Matlin and Martin Sheen was released in the US a couple of weeks before The Sandlot, so it still would've been in theaters. And in the opening scene, a man arrives on horseback to a museum, pulls out a gun and shoots a female security guard, killing her. Can't recall or verify the roses, but seems too close to be a coincidence. Here's a pic from that scene and the trailer is below, see if they jog your husband's memory:



